# How to pass multiple userInputs into ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to pass 5 user edited `EditText` fields into an `ArrayList` to populate a `ToggleButon` in the next activity.

Not sure why I'm getting `"method call expected"` error in my java code.

I've already initiated my `userInput ArrayList` withing my activity but still hitting a wall.

Any code suggestions or links to some useful documentation would be much appreciated

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText venueOption1;
EditText venueOption2;
EditText venueOption3;
EditText venueOption4;
EditText venueOption5;

Button UpdateVenueButton;

public static ArrayList<String> userInput;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    venueOption1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption1);
    venueOption2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption2);
    venueOption3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption3);
    venueOption4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption4);
    venueOption5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption5);


    UpdateVenueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    userInput = new ArrayList<>(4);




    UpdateVenueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            venueOption1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption1);
            getUserInput(userInput.get(0));

            venueOption2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption2);
            getUserInput(userInput(1));

            venueOption3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption3);
            getUserInput(userInput(2));

            venueOption4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption4);
            getUserInput(userInput(3));

            venueOption5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.venueOption5);
            getUserInput(userInput(4));

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), VenueOptions.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: To help us help you it would be better if you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the actual error text/stacktrace.

Comment: Please put code in your questions, not links

Comment: Also `public static Arraylist`  is a bad idea for passing data between Activities. Learn to use Intent extras  correctly

Comment: Thanks for the tips. First time stackoverflow user.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because java is expecting you to call a method on the arraylist and instead you are just putting parentheses near it. This has no meaning in java syntax. Array elements can be accessed directly with [] but ArrayList elements can't be accessed directly, you have to use the get(index) method.

Instead of

```
getUserInput(userInput(0));
```

you should do

```
getUserInput(userInput.get(0));
```